# SQL Server INFORMATION_SCHEMA reports different float precision than ADO.NET GetSchemaTable()?

Tags: .net, sql-server, ado.net

For a SQL Server column declared as `float`, the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` reports a numeric precision of 53, whereas the ADO.NET `SqlDataReader.GetSchemaTable()` method reports 15.  What is the reason for this apparent discrepancy?

Here is a minimal code example in VB:

```vb
Private Sub MinimalCodeExample(conn As DbConnection)
  Try
    CreateTestTable(conn)
    Dim precisionFromInformationSchema As Integer =
      GetPrecisionFromInformationSchema(conn) ' 53
    Dim precisionFromADONETSchemaTable As Integer =
      GetPrecisionFromADONETSchemaTable(conn) ' 15

    ' Why does this assertion fail, 53 <> 15?
    Debug.Assert(precisionFromInformationSchema = precisionFromADONETSchemaTable)
  Finally
    CleanUpTestTable(conn)
  End Try
End Sub

Private Sub CreateTestTable(conn As DbConnection)
  Dim cmd As DbCommand = conn.CreateCommand()
  cmd.CommandText = "CREATE TABLE STACKOVERFLOWEXAMPLE(value float)"
  cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
End Sub

Private Function GetPrecisionFromInformationSchema(conn As DbConnection) As Integer
  Using cmd As DbCommand = conn.CreateCommand()
    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT NUMERIC_PRECISION FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME='STACKOVERFLOWEXAMPLE'"
    Return CInt(cmd.ExecuteScalar())
  End Using
End Function

Private Function GetPrecisionFromADONETSchemaTable(conn As DbConnection) As Integer
  Using cmd As DbCommand = conn.CreateCommand()
    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT value FROM STACKOVERFLOWEXAMPLE"
    Using reader As DbDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.SchemaOnly Or CommandBehavior.KeyInfo)
      Using dt As DataTable = reader.GetSchemaTable()
        Return CInt(dt.Select("ColumnName='value'").Single()("NumericPrecision"))
      End Using
    End Using
  End Using
End Function

Private Sub CleanUpTestTable(conn As DbConnection)
  Using cmd As DbCommand = conn.CreateCommand()
    cmd.CommandText = "DROP TABLE STACKOVERFLOWEXAMPLE"
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
  End Using
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, 53 is in `bits`, 15 is in `digits`.

> float [ (n) ] Where n is the number of bits that are used to store the
>   mantissa of the float number in scientific notation and, therefore,
>   dictates the precision and storage size. If n is specified, it must be
>   a value between 1 and 53. The default value of n is 53.

[float and real (TSQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/float-and-real-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

And in ADO.NET the "NumericPrecision" for all numeric data types indicates the number of decimal digits the data type can store.